# Suppressing warnings for a printf-like function in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma, variadic, variadic-macros

I have a **legacy** logging printf-like function in C:

```
namespace legacy
{
    void DoLog(const char* format,...);
}
```

If is only visible if a corresponding macro is defined (this is **legacy** too):

```
#ifdef LOG
# define Log legacy::DoLog
#else
# define Log /* Nothing */
#endif
```

I have some C++ code, which calls this log like:

```
Log("Logging started!");
```

When the `LOG` macro is not defined, `Log("Something");` turns into `("Something");` which is unused code.

I need to suppress these warnings in GCC, and do it only once, of course, so I wrap `Log` into `MyLog` as `#define MyLog Log` and try this:

```
#define MyLog(...) \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push"); \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wunused-value\""); \
    Log(__VA_ARGS__); \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop");
```

But these pragmas for some reason do not have any effect
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

I would better use inline C++ wrapper with templates for the perfect wrapping, but I cannot cope with it yet...

Any suggestions how to suppress these warnings?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sooo why not `#define Log(...)`? `how to suppress these warnings?` I think it is _preferable_ to have printf warnings even with disabled logging. Then, in case you enable logging, your code is valid and you don't have to deal with a wall of warnings. Consider adding `__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 1, 2)))` and doing `#define Log(...) 0&&legacy::DoLog(__VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
#define Log(...)
```

and then `Log("Logging started!");` expands to just `;` instead of `("Logging started!");`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come to the two following solutions:

C++ style inline function, with suppressed warnings and basic Windows and Linux platform definitions used:

```
template<typename... Args>
inline void MyLog(const char* format, Args... args)
{
#ifndef LOG
# ifdef _MSC_VER // Windows
#  pragma warning(push)
#  pragma warning(disable: 4548)
# elif defined(__GNUC__) // Linux
#  pragma GCC diagnostic push
#  pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
# endif
#endif
    Log(format, (args,...));
#ifndef LOG
# ifdef _MSC_VER // Windows
#  pragma warning(pop)
# elif defined(__GNUC__) // Linux
#  pragma GCC diagnostic pop
# endif
#endif
}
```

C style wrapper macro, even without any warnings suppression needed (thanks to @KamilCuk and @user253751):

```
#ifndef LOG
# define MyLog(...)
#else
# define MyLog(...) Log(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```